# complex dom traversal using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-traversal

Code for 01.js:

```
var childp = document.getElementById('selected-plays').getElementsByTagName('li');
function getElementsRequired(childp) {
var listitem = [];
var i = 0;
for(i = 0 ; i <childp.length; i++){
//   console.log(childp[i].childNodes.length); 
//condition to filter leaf nodes which are 'li'.
if ((childp[i].childNodes.length - 1))

    listitem.push(childp[i]);
}
//Loop for removing li's which are not direct sibling of ul with class="selected-plays"
for(i =0 ; i<listitem.length; i++){
    if(listitem[i].childNodes[1].getElementsByTagName('a').length){
    console.log(listitem[i].childNodes[1].getElementsByTagName('a'));
    listitem.splice(i,1);
  }
}
return listitem;
}
```

in console:

```
 getElementsRequired(childp);
```

code for body of 01.html:

```
<body>
<h2>Selected Shakephere plays</h2>
<ul id="selected-plays">
    <li>Comedies
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/asyoulikeit/">As You Like It</a></li>
            <li>All's Well That Ends Well</li>
            <li>A Midsummer Night's Dream</li>
            <li>Twelfth Night</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Tragedies
        <ul>
            <li><a href="hamlet.pdf">Hamlet</a></li>
            <li>Macbeth</li>
            <li>Romeo and Juliet</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Histories
        <ul>
            <li>Henry IV (<a href="mailto:henryiv@king.co.uk">email</a>)
                <ul>
                    <li>Part I</li>
                    <li>Part II</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.shakespeare.co.uk/henryv.htm">Henry V</a></li>
            <li>Richard II</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Elements to be selected are first `'li'siblings of class="selected-plays"`. The problem is now that traversal of dom gives more element blocks , but it should give only 3 blocks namely `"Comedies"`,`"Tragedies"`,`"Histories"`. How do I remove the extra element block which is number 4 and contains Henry IV?

jsbin for this is here: http://jsbin.com/vital/2/edit

Comment: The `ul` has no `li` siblings. It has `li` children as well as deeper descendants. To make it simple, use `.querySelectorAll` to only get the direct children. `document.querySelectorAll("ul.selected-plays > li")`

Comment: ...some other potential issues would come from using `.childNodes` which includes your whitespace as TextNodes instead of `.children`, which only gives you elements, as well as using `.splice()` to remove items during a forward iteration, meaning you'll skip an item every time one is removed.

Comment: ...but if you wanted to support IE6/7, then instead of `querySelectorAll`, do this to only get the child `li` elements: `document.getElementById('selected-plays').children`

Comment: this question is more logic oriented than to use readeymade solutions. Theme is how using the above method we can achieve what is required . @cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$.clone()` and `$.remove()` to make this easier. Clone will give you a new element so that you don't destroy the HTML in your DOM. Remove will then remove the child UL from the newly cloned LI.

http://jsbin.com/jeloloto/2/edit

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var $categoryLIs = $("#selected-plays").children("li");
  var categories = getCategories($categoryLIs);
  debugger;
})

var getCategories = function($elements) {
  var categories = new Array();

  $elements.each(function(index) {
    var element = $elements[index];
    var newElement = $.clone(element);
    $(newElement).find('ul').remove();
    categories.push(newElement);
  });

  return categories;
}
```